# PyQGIS script (.py) runs correctly on Windows but not on Mac

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, geopackage

I wrote a script that takes a vector layer already present in my QGIS project and refactor fields as I wish.
I created the script to avoid doing plenty of times the same refactorization manually every time, since this kind of refactoization occurs sistematically.
That's the code I wrote:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: ascii -*-

from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject
import processing

input = "Compendio_Fx"
output = ".\\Compendio_NomeComune_invio_dati.gpkg"  

processing.run("native:refactorfields", {'INPUT': input, 'FIELDS_MAPPING': 
[{'expression':'\"ID_OGGETTO\"','name':"ID_OGGETTO_COMPARTO", 'length':17, 'precision':0,'type':10},
{'expression': '\"SUL_realiz\"','name': 'SUL_REALIZZATA','length': 10,'precision': 3,'type': 6},
{'expression': '\"VOL_potenz\"','name': 'VOLUME_POTENZIALE','length': 10,'precision': 3,'type': 6},
{'expression': '\"Trav_VOL\"','name': 'TRAVASO_VOLUME','length': 10,'precision': 3,'type': 6},
{'expression': '\"VOL_realiz\"','name': 'VOLUME_REALIZZATO','length': 10,'precision': 3,'type': 6},
{'expression': '\"Computo\"','name': 'TIPO_COMPUTO_SUL_R_VOL_R','length': 255,'precision': 0,'type': 10},
{'expression': '\"TX_SFRU\"','name': 'TASSO_SFRUTTAMENTO','length': 10,'precision': 3,'type': 6},
{'expression': '\"Stat_costr\"','name': 'STATO_COSTRUZIONE','length': 255,'precision': 0,'type': 10},
{'expression': '\"Stat_urb\"','name': 'STATO_URBANIZZAZIONE','length': 255,'precision': 0,'type': 10},
{'expression': '\"COD_ZonaTI\"','name': 'COD_ZONA_CANTONE','length': 30,'precision': 0,'type': 10},
{'expression': '\"Note\"','name': 'TESTO_SUPPLEMENTARE','length': 255,'precision': 0,'type': 10},
{'expression': '\"IS_Fx\"','name': 'INDICE_SFRUTTAMENTO_MASSIMO','length': 10,'precision': 3,'type': 6},
{'expression': '\"IE_Fx\"','name': 'INDICE_EDIFICABILITA_MASSIMO','length': 10,'precision': 3,'type': 6},
{'expression': '\"G.A.\"','name': 'CORREZIONE_POTENZIALE_SUL_VOL','length': 10,'precision': 3,'type': 6},
{'expression': '\"Consumo_AB\"','name': 'CONSUMO_TEO_UI_ABITAZIONE','length': 10,'precision': 3,'type': 6},
{'expression': '\"Consumo_LA\"','name': 'CONSUMO_TEO_UI_LAVORO','length': 10,'precision': 3,'type': 6},
{'expression': '\"Consumo_TU\"','name': 'CONSUMO_TEO_UI_TURISMO','length': 10,'precision': 3,'type': 6},
{'expression': '\"Quota_AB\"','name': 'IPOTESI_QUOTA_ABITANTI','length': 10,'precision': 3,'type': 6},
{'expression': '\"Quota_LA\"','name': 'IPOTESI_QUOTA_LAVORO','length': 10,'precision': 3,'type': 6},
{'expression': '\"Quota_TU\"','name': 'IPOTESI_QUOTA_TURISMO','length': 10,'precision': 3,'type': 6},
{'expression': '\"TX_SFRU_15\"','name': 'TASSO_SFRUTTAMENTO_15_ANNI','length': 10,'precision': 3,'type': 6}], 
'OUTPUT': output})
```

Everithing works fine as long as I'm working  on my Windows machine, where I also elaborated the script (and done all my tries before to succeed the task).

As I shared the code to a friend of mine working on the same project, but with a Mac computer instead, but the execution of the same script, on the same project contained in the same folder (so no problems of path compatibility) gives him this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/code.py”, line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File “<input>“, line 1, in <module>
  File “<string>“, line 10, in <module>
  File “/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/tools/general.py”, line 108, in run
    return Processing.runAlgorithm(algOrName, parameters, onFinish, feedback, context)
  File “/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/core/Processing.py”, line 174, in runAlgorithm
    ret, results = execute(alg, parameters, context, feedback, catch_exceptions=False)
  File “/Applications/QGIS-LTR.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/plugins/processing/gui/AlgorithmExecutor.py”, line 71, in execute
    results, ok = alg.run(parameters, context, feedback, {}, False)
_core.QgsProcessingException: Impossibile creare il layer .\Compendio_NomeComune_invio_dati.gpkg: Creazione della sorgente dati fallita (errore OGR: sqlite3_open(.\Compendio_NomeComune_invio_dati.gpkg) failed: unable to open database file)
```

Someone can explain me why this happens on Mac and how to solve this kind of issue?

Comment: Remove the backslash? `output = "Compendio_NomeComune_invio_dati.gpkg"`

Comment: It doesn't work. I've also tried these options:
output = "./Compendio_NomeComune_invio_dati.gpkg"
output = ".//Compendio_NomeComune_invio_dati.gpkg"
output = ".\Compendio_NomeComune_invio_dati.gpkg"
none of these options worked... I thought that the first option I wrote (output = "./Compendio_NomeComune_invio_dati.gpkg") was the one, since relative paths on mac can be defined this way. Unfortunately it's not the case, apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, even if it doesn't solve all my doubts.

The mac computer does not seem to recognise the relative path given, in any of the tried formulations (".\", ".", ".//", "./").
To bypass the problem, I called the function returning the path of the project I'm working on:

```
proj = QgsProject.instance().fileName()
```

and then another function, that simply gives me the path of the directory of the path:

```
path = os.path.dirname(proj)
```

Now, instead of providing the relative path, I can compose the path of the output file as I wish in this way:

```
output = path + "/Compendio_NomeComune_invio_dati.gpkg"
```

Anyway, if someone can help me understand what is the probem when passing a relative path to a apple machine, it will be great!